# Error Connection REFUSED for facebook thumbnail pictures

Tags: facebook

Any idea for below errors?

```
https://fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/v/t1.0-0/p173x172/150…e52348e93b&oe=57807AF2&__gda__=1467438300_df728026da1ca2a06d1917e687758d7e
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Facebook thumbnails pictures not loading for some and loading for others. I have tried different browsers and experienced the same issue. I've also tried disabling my firewall, clearing my cache, flushing my DNS, using a VPN, etc.

Comment: Please, correct your link

Comment: those are from inspect element result.

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking. Where does this happen, on facebook.com directly? Or on your own site, where you embedded those URLs? And if so, where did you get that URL from in the first place – as a result of an API call, or …?